# How to prepend text to a filestream?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, header

I'm trying to write a custom header (text) to a file and will also have to remove the header when *releasing* the file.

I am trying:

```
var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(headerText);
file.SetLength(buffer.Length + data.Length);
file.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
//then write the rest of the file
```

And then when *releasing* (to skip header):

```
var data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(headerText);
inFile.Seek(data.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

But this doesn't work. First, it leaves spaces between the header text, and reading it returns incorrect data. How best can I go about achieving this?

Comment: (Seeking just changes where you'll start reading/writing the next time you read or write. It doesn't change the file.)

Comment: Yh, that's what I'm trying to do. Just noticed it's working but it's appending a whole lot of empty space at the end of the file. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Probably the way you're setting the file length. You're setting the file length to the data size plus the buffer size, so unless the buffer is completely full, you'll have garbage (including blanks) at the end of it.